# Need help parsing through JSON Object in JMETER

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I'm testing an application that calls one API, gets a bunch of work orders, then only the work order ID's are passed to another API to display on the page.

The format they need to be in is: {"workOrderIds":["12345","123456"]}

I'm using the JSON Extractor with the following Path Expressions:
$..workOrderNumber

then I'm using the JSR223 PostProcessor and using the following script:
props.put("workOrderNumber", "${workOrderNumber}";

The problem is, that its creating the object like so when I add the variable into the POST Request body of the second request:
{"workOrderIds":["12345, 123456"]}

essentially, I just need to make sure that each value has quotations, but not sure how to make this happen. Sorry if this seems simple, I'm fairly new to QA and have spent several hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: I got a little closer, using this script in the JSR223 processor:

vars.put('workOrderIds', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).findResults{entry -> entry.workOrderNumber}).toPrettyString())


But now, it has these quotes before the array:

{workOrderIds":"["12345",123456","1234567"]"}

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide a comprehensive answer without seeing the source JSON, maybe it worth trying explicitly casting the filtering result to an [Integer](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Integer.html) like:

```
vars.put('workOrderIds', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).findResults { entry -> entry.workOrderNumber as int }).toPrettyString())
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)